Does Chrome/Chromium support low-level plugins (like dynamic C libs)?
I'd like to extend Chrome/Chromium functionality at the browser level with more power than is available in Chrome extensions.
Ideally, it would be great if I could write a plugin in Rust, compiled to a dynamic C library that hooks into/extends Chromium functionality.
Does such a capability exist?
I realize there are probably security concerns with this; which is probably why Chromium doesn't seem to have this capability - but it would be helpful for me as I could develop tools to aid in my local development experience.
EDIT:
I guess I could compile Chromium myself with my extensions built in, that might be a solution. I believe it's possible to enable Google Account Sync with Chromium?

Yes, it supports native extensions. They communicate with Chromium using Native messaging via stdin/stdout in a native extension. You can take the example here or look for other example of "Native messaging".
